# Controlling for age in logistic regression and I'm stuck in circular reasoning

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, interpretation, predictor

I recently completed a research project that involved motor learning in control (non-disease) subjects.  The outcome of the motor learning is binary: 1 - subject learned, 0 - subject didn't learn. 13 out of 30 (43%) of control subjects learned. I ran a best-subset logistic regression procedure and ended up with a good model that predicted the outcome correctly 88% of the time (on a test set). The model had two continuous variables that reflect motor performance, A and B.

Now, I am expanding these findings to a disease group. 2 of 20 (10%) of the disease subjects learned. With a Fisher's test that is a significant difference from 13 out of 30. **I want to know if it is the disease or the motor performance that causes the reduced learning in the disease group.**  The *problem* is that my disease group is older than my control group. (t(48)=-2.3, p=0.03).  Of course, variable A is correlated with age, but variable B is not.

Here's why I've gotten myself into a circular argument:

1. If I compare the control and disease group on variables A and B with age as a covariate, there is no difference (A; F(1,47) = 1, p = 0.3) (B; F(1,47)= 4, p=0.05).
2. The original model (Learning ~ A + B) works well if I just include the data from the disease group without adding diagnosis to the model.  That makes me think that motor performance (not diagnosis) predicts learning.
3. If I add age into the model (Learning ~ A + B + age), age is not a significant contributor (Wald = 0.6, p = 0.4), but A and B are significant contributors. That also makes me think motor performance predicts learning.
4. If I add diagnosis to the model either with age *or* without age (Learning ~ A + B + age + Dx; Learning ~ A + B + age + Dx), Dx is never a significant contributor.  That makes me think that performance predicts learning.

**So, if it's A and B that predict learning, and I have the same levels for A and B across my groups when controlling for age, why am I seeing such a difference in the binary outcome for my groups?**

Maybe I'm missing an interaction term, or this is simply because linear and logistic regression work differently.  What's real?

Comment: In step 3, is that the model with both disease and non-disease groups included?

Comment: ... also, could the effects of the disease be affecting motor learning via their effects on the motor performance variables $A$ and $B$?